# parsing complex string using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying the whole day to find a good way for parsing some strings with a shell script. the strings are used as calling parameter for some applications.

they looks like:

```
parsingParams -c "id=uid5 prog=/opt/bin/example arg=\"-D -t5 >/dev/null 1>&2\" info='fdhff fd'" start
```

I'm only allowed to use shell-script. I tried to use some sed and cut commands but nothing works fine.

My tries are like:

```
prog=$(echo $@ | cut -d= -f3 | sed 's|\s.*$||')
```

that return the correct value of prog but for the value of arg I couldn't find a good way to get it.
the info parameter is optional also it may be left.
may any one have a good idea that can solve this problem?
many thanks in advance

Comment: Please describe exactly what you want parsed, i.e. which parts you need separated. That has significant impact on what a "correct" solution would look like.

Comment: @DevSolar I would like to extract the values of id, prog, arg and info.

Comment: From within `parsingParams`, which gets them as `-c "..."` parameter?

Comment: @DevSolar exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eval

```
$ eval "id=uid5 prog=/opt/bin/example arg=\"-D -t5 >/dev/null 1>&2\" info='fdhff fd'"
$ echo $id
uid5
$ echo $prog
/opt/bin/example
$ echo $arg
-D -t5 >/dev/null 1>&2
$ echo $info
fdhff fd
```

Comment: if it were user-supplied then it could be requested one var at a time

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you could use `eval` to let the shell parse your input string, but if you don't control the input (if it comes from an unreliable source), that will introduce a major vulnerability (imagine an attacker somehow passes `-c "rm -rf /"` to your program).

A safer way would be to explicitly specify allowed forms of user input.

The problem you have with splitting on space (with `cut`) if the space is quoted, can be avoided if you specify valid fields (*content*, not *separator*), for example in GNU `awk`, you can use [`FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content):

```
$ params="id=uid5 prog=/opt/bin/example arg=\"-D -t5 >/dev/null 1>&2\" info='fdhff fd'"
$ awk -v FPAT="[^=]+=(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^ ]*) *" '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' <<<"$params"
id=uid5 
prog=/opt/bin/example 
arg="-D -t5 >/dev/null 1>&2" 
info='fdhff fd'
```

Valid fields will be in one of the following forms:

```
var="val with spaces"
var='val with spaces'
var=val_no_spaces
```

Now with assignments split (one per line, assuming newline is not allowed in `params`), you can process them further, even with `cut`:

```
$ awk ... | cut -d $'\n' -f3
arg="-D -t5 >/dev/null 1>&2"
```